# Listen to NetUtil.asyncFetch progress

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

How to listen to the progress of a `NetUtil.asyncFetch`? I know it returns the nsIChannel, but have no idea to track down the `notificationCallbacks`.

Answer (score 0):

> but have no idea to track down the notificationCallbacks.

they're a property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIChannel#Attributes